# How to arrange elements that is there in a single column to multiple using sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

My File content:

```
Apple
Banana
orange
Donkey
Elephant
Fox
Good
```

I am trying to arrange elements that is there in a single column(as shown above) into two columns as shown below:

Expected output:

```
Apple          Banana
Orange         Donkey
Elephant       Fox
Good
```

Is there any way in Sed or awk to achieve this?

Comment: `man pr`... Many different options for how to re-columnize things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
$ awk 'ORS=(NR%2)?" ":"\n"' input
Apple Banana
orange Donkey
Elephant Fox
Good
```

**OR**

```
$ awk 'ORS=(NR%2)?FS:RS' input | column -t
Apple     Banana
orange    Donkey
Elephant  Fox
Good
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Is there a way to arrange in equal space as shown in my expected output? (I mean Banana, Donkey, Fox should be arranged in straight line)

Comment: You could add  `END {if (NR%2) print "\n" }` for trailing newline

Comment: @Kumar You can use the `column` utility. I have edited my answer to include that as well. Hope it helps you

Comment: @Dinesh That is nice. But  I dont think its required when you are using `column` to format the output.

Comment: @EdMorton But isnt it always the value of `ORS` since FS and RS cannot be null it will evaluate true right?

Comment: @EdMorton The value that is assigned to the left hand side is of an expression is the value of an expression(same as in c) hence am pretty sure that the `ORS` value is used for evaluation. By default `FS` is set to space and `RS` is set to `\n` hence is I think its safe to write so in the script (ofcourse from my limited knowledge)

Comment: Got it, so the only caveat is that if you change the value of FS or RS to a null string (e.g. for parsing one char at a time) or to a value that evaluates to numeric zero then you need to re-write the script to move the condition into an action block and add a new action to print the record unconditionally. IMHO I'd just always use `awk '{ORS=(NR%2?OFS:RS)}1'` but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah. Since we are not unseting or modifying the values of separators, its safe to write so

Comment: @EdMorton I dont think you would ever need to write something like that. The two cases where `ORS=somthing` evaluates false are `ORS=""` and `ORS=0`. If you are planning to assing these values to `ORS` then only you need to move them to action part, You can even skip the action part as `awk 'ORS="" 1'`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R you are right. I had added comment before I saw your post. BTW, I learned something from your answer about ORS, thanks!

Comment: @nu11p01n73R that would set ORS to `1` instead of `""`. The code I wrote is the minimum you need to do this robustly.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry I missed that